# Better way to handle common headers and root?

Tags: android-annotations

Is there a better way to set bearer like a global config rather than setting it each time like this:

```
restClient.setBearerAuth(TokenStore.getInstance().getLocalToken());
```

The same for root url, is there a global config rather than setting it like this:

```
String root= Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.whiteLabelApiBaseHost)
restClient.setRootUrl(root);
```

In retrofit, there is something like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
                            .getResources().getString(R.string.whiteLabelApiBaseHost))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set root url you can use this method, substituting the string with a constant

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://company.com/ajax/services", converters = { MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class }, interceptors = MyAuthInterceptor.class)
public interface MyRestClient {
    @Get("/events")
    EventList getEvents();
}
```

Note that we set an interceptor in the arguments of the @Rest annotation.
So create a class like this:

```
@EBean(scope = Scope.Singleton)
public class MyAuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Bean
MyAuthStore authStore;

public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    HttpAuthentication auth = new HttpBasicAuthentication(authStore.getUsername(), authStore.getPassword());
    headers.setAuthorization(auth);
    return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

Now before executing request MyAuthInterceptor.intercept() is called and you can set your authentication data as you prefer

In your main build.gradle file you can add inside android element

```
productFlavors {

    development {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_URL_BASE", "\"dev.xxx.com/rest\""
    }

    test {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_URL_BASE", "\"test.xxx.com/rest\""
    }

    production {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_URL_BASE", "\"production.xxx.com/rest\""
    }
}
```

Then in your @Rest annotation you can use this code to get current flavor value:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "https://" + BuildConfig.SERVICE_URL_BASE)
```

Now you can select what build variant to use (variant = flavor + buildType) to use desired value. To select variant you can use corresponding view, it should be present on the left of android studio.

This technique is useful to avoid creating flavor's package tree only to use different variabiles

Comment: Thanks for answer, how would I use `R.string.whiteLabelApiBaseHost` in `@Rest` ? Can I set rootUrl within the interceptor?

Comment: I don't think you can set rootUrl within the interceptor, surely not easily. why do you need this? may be you can solve in another way. and why do you need to get rootUrl from string resources? If you need to use different url based on environment i suggest to use gradle build variables

Comment: Can you please write an example of using gradle build variable to set RootUrl at `@Rest` based on environment?